# Javascript interop assignment in Clojurescript

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, clojurescript

Dumb question: how do I do Javascript assignment in Clojurescript ? I'm using a Javascript lib and need to set the value of an object's field like `obj.this=that;` - I don't know Javascript so maybe there's a .set method ?

Comment: Don't preemptively dis your own questions -- this wasn't inherently obvious to me either.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try some thing like

```
(set! (.-property foo) 5)
```

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
(aset foo "property" 5)
```

Be aware, that [symbolic references may fail](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2013/03/28/two-ways-to-access-properties-in-clojurescript/).